# How should I use Properties in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

Im not sure because in Java getter/setter are looking a little bit different but whats the "c# way" to code this stuff?

Option a.)

```
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private int time;

    public int Time
    {
        get { return time; }
        set { time = value; }
    }
```

b.)

```
    private string _name;
    private int _time;

    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public int time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set { _time = value; }
    }
```

c.)

```
   public string name {get; set;}
   public int time {get; set;}
```

Ok there are some examples. What would look better? Should I write all the private variable declarations first then the properties or should I group my variable and property declaration next to each other.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about d, following .NET naming conventions:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Time { get; set; } // Odd type for time, admittedly...
```

Don't bother writing the property manually yourself unless you do something non-trivial in it.

If you *do* write the property implementation manually, it's up to you how you name the private variable. Personally I'd use:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { /* whatever */ }
    set { /* whatever */ }
}
```

... but if you want to use underscores, that's your prerogative.

As for ordering of members - that's even more your own choice. Assuming you're working with a team, talk with the team and see what the local convention is.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't need access to the underlying backing fields, then auto-properties are the suggested way which is (C).  However, according to .NET naming convention they should be PascalCase.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Time { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6):

The first two are just *naming convensions* that you should choose based on the company/dev group or your own decision.

The third case is the short way of decalring the **same property**, where the actual `field` will be generated by runtime itself.

Short Pros: *it's short and easy*.

Short cons: *Can not put something **inside** geter/setter, can not put breakpoint in Visual Studio*...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case (no logic on getter or setter) the best option is `C` (with a small change on properties names to follow C# standards)

```
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public int Time {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the case, when you define the fields an underscore character is used, and if you just need a simple getter/setter there is no need to define the fields yourself because the compiler will define them for you in the background.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the option, most others already posted.

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public int Time {get; set;}
```

Note, that you can make change protection-level on the setter and getter individually, e.g.

```
public string Name {get; protected set;}
protected int Time {get; private set;}
```

You can only use a higher protection than applied to the hole property.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public int Time {get; set;}
```